# layout issues with multiple divs using jquery css()

Tags: jquery, css

I have a number of divs that I'm trying to layout. The current layout is perfect, see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgyB/).

Essentially I have a video player, represented by "Video player here". Beside it I have some tips and resources. Under the video player I have a table with buttons. Click a button to see what happens.

The info message triggered through jquery `.css()` should be under the video player and between the video player and table.

I'm sure I'm just missing something in the `.css()` but can't find the right combination to lay this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ahem ... you are not doing any CSS positioning ... so why do you expect the box to have a certain position on screen? What about `position: absolute` or `clear:both` or similar?

Comment: @devnull69 I was, but removed it. I tried float: left like one of the answers but that doesn't work. But clear: left does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to your css:

```
#quote {
 clear:left;   
}
```

​That will make it show up under the video message.

Answer (score 0):

Add style for #quote in css

```
#quote
{
float: left;
}
```

or in JS,

```
$('#quote').css('float','left');
```